# ggplot2 error object 'Name' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a novice in R and I try to create bubble plot with ggplo2 but I'm receiving this error below.

```
library(ggplot2)

 p<-read.csv("Bullespecies.csv",row.names=1)

head(p,5)

  Longitude Latitude   Abstro   Sestro     Abmy    Semyr
8      3.250   42.828 11.77143 12.94157 125.6134 37.27682
9      3.728   43.314 36.67143 12.94157  73.5714 37.27682
10     3.805   42.918 10.00000 13.97850 168.8333 40.26357
12     3.600   43.054 22.00000 15.31267 180.0000 44.10653
14     3.570   42.875 27.89474 12.94157  77.7945 37.27682

rownames(p)

 [1] "8"  "9"  "10" "12" "14" "15" "17" "18" "20" "22" "23" "24" "25" "28" "29"
[16] "30" "32" "34" "35" "37" "39" "41"


mytheme <- theme_bw() +
    theme(text = element_text(colour="black"),
    axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5)))

p1<-ggplot(p,aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size=Abmy))+
        geom_point(shape=21,colour="black",fill="grey")+
        geom_text(aes(y=Latitude+.1,label=Name),size=4,vjust=1.45)

p1+mytheme

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objcet 'Name' not found
```

what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is simple. You don't have a variable called `Name`, while you are passing it to `geom_text` for some reason. Also, please refrain from spamming SO with exactly same questions

Comment: @tonytonov, the other question already marked as a duplicate of this one, so we need to leave at least one question open

Comment: True, this is obviously a question which does not fulfill the highest standards and is a proper duplicate of another question. But is it really necessary to discourage someoine who is obviously new to `R` and to SO by downvotes, not answering, flagging both question to close ? At least this question shows enough effort and has enough content to give a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

It was mentioned already that your `data.frame` `p` is lacking of a column named `Name`. Since you explicitly mention the rownames of `p` in your example, I assume that these are the names you want to plot. In this case you have to add them as a proper column to your data:

```
p$Name <- rownames(p)
```

With your code you already posted you can produce then a plot looking like this:

[image]